# Error al escribir archivo en C#

Tags: c#

estoy intentando hacer un programa en el cual necesito escribir en un archivo de texto, si el archivo no existe, se crea correctamente, el problema es cuando lo quiero escribir, dado que salta el error que se ve en el titulo de esta pregunta. El código que tengo es este:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace main
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Producto pro = new Producto();
            pro.agregar();
        }
    }
}
```

Y en la clase producto tengo esto:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
namespace main
{
    public class Producto
    {
        public void agregar()
        {
            string ruta = "D:\\crudCS\\ListaDeProductos.txt";
            if (!File.Exists(ruta))
            {
                File.Create(ruta);
                string texto = "Hermoso";
                File.AppendAllLines(ruta, new String[] { texto });
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("El archivo ya existe y esta pulenta");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/zUKztC3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que estas utilizando mal la clase "File".
Cuando haces en tu codigo esto:

```
File.Create(ruta);
```

Estas llamando a un constructor que te devuelve un objeto de tipo "filestream" que es el encargado de escribir cosas en tu nuevo archivo.
Lo podes usar bien de la siguiente forma:

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Create(ruta))
    {
                
               
    }
```

Esto lo que hace es crearte el objeto que te mencione antes, el "filestream". ahora para usarlo lo podes usar así:

```
String[] strings = new String[] {"hola", "como", "estas" };
using (FileStream fs = File.Create(ruta))
{
    foreach (string s in strings)
    {
          var texto = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(s + "\n");
          fs.Write(texto,  0, texto.Length);
    }
               
}
```

Lo que hace el código de arriba básicamente es pasar el string a un array de bytes(que es el tipo de datos que filestream pide en el metodo write) para poder asi escribir el archivo.

Eso seria todo!

Te paso todo el código entero que a mi me funciona:

```
        string ruta = @"path/de/tu/txt.txt";
        if (!File.Exists(ruta))
        {
            String[] strings = new String[] {"hola", "como", "estas" };
            using (FileStream fs = File.Create(ruta))
            {
                foreach (string s in strings)
                {
                    var texto = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(s + "\n");
                    fs.Write(texto,  0, texto.Length);
                }
               
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("El archivo ya existe y esta pulenta");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

El error es que el archivo cuando lo estas intentando editar esta abierto  por otro proceso una forma sencilla de crear y escribir seria usando streamwriter y using para que cierre las conexiones una vez finalice la actuacion (que es lo que te esta ocurriendo)

```
string path = @"c:\temp\MyTest.txt";
if (!File.Exists(path))
{
    // Crea el archivo y escribe.
    using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
    {
        sw.WriteLine("Hello");
        sw.WriteLine("And");
        sw.WriteLine("Welcome");
    }   
}

// abre y escribe.
using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path))
{
    string s = "";
    while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

Pero no es la única forma mira te dejo un ejemplo de un código mio "feo" que lo uso para tracear multiples aplicaciones  el funcionamiento es sencillo

```
EscribirTraza(string.Format("## no se han encontrado resultados para la consulta -->  {0}", "error en la consulta"), "C:\Users", InformationLevel.Error);
```

Llamamos al método pasandole el tipo de nivel de error y según el nivel de error que este configurado escribe la traza o no en este caso error es nivel 2 por lo que al ser 2 o menos si se escribiría

```
using System;
using System.IO;



namespace Xxxxxxx.Comun
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Traza
    /// </summary>
    public class TrazaCorreo
    {
        #region VARIABLES GLOBALES

        //ruta donde se guardan los logs
        // private static string LogFilePath = "C:/xxxxxx";

        //objeto que permite bloquear el acceso al fichero de Log
        private static object obj_lock = new object();

        #endregion VARIABLES GLOBALES
        //enumeral para los tipos de traza
        public enum InformationLevel
        {
            Notrace = 0,
            Critical = 1,
            Error = 2,
            Warning = 3,
            Information = 4
        }

        public TrazaCorreo()
        {
        }

        public static void EscribirTraza(string texto, string strRuta, InformationLevel tracelevel, string LogFileName = null)
        {
            
            var traceDefault = 2;//puedes sacarlo de un web config
            if ((int)tracelevel <= traceDefault)
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(strRuta);//para asegurarnos que el directorio existe

                #region VARIABLES

                //Obtener la fecha actual
                DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
                //Nombre del fichero se corresponde con el dia (1 log por dia)
                if (LogFileName == null)
                {
                    LogFileName = string.Format("xxxxxx_{0}.log", currentDate.ToString("ddMMyyyy"));
                }
                else
                {
                    LogFileName = LogFileName + "_" + currentDate.ToString("ddMMyyyy") + ".log";
                }
                //calculamos la hora
                string horaActual = currentDate.ToString("HH:mm:ss");

                #endregion VARIABLES

                #region MANEJO FICHERO

                /*
             * Insertar el texto en el Log del día
             * Si es el primer Log del día, el archivo no existe y se crea automáticamente
             *
             * El acceso al fichero está controlado por lock(), de forma que si dos hilos
             * intentan acceder a la escritura simultaneamente, sus peticiones se encolarán una detrás de otra
             */
                try
                {
                    lock (obj_lock)
                    {
                        StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText(strRuta + LogFileName);
                        writer.WriteLine(horaActual + "\t" + tracelevel.ToString() + "\t\t===>\t" + texto);
                        writer.Close();
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException a)
                {//esto esta muy feo asi
                }
                catch (Exception) { }

                #endregion MANEJO FICHERO
            }
        }
    }
}
```